# I have this simple responsive website im working, but i have an issue

Tags: html, css, web, web-deployment

I wrote this html/css code and i have it layed out responsively
but when i resize it to responsive view the text on one of the main
info areas has a big square gap in it!! I tried margin and padding and like
everything. It confuses me. Also on my mobile version of the nav bar, i would like the
items to display line by line, but they wont break. All help would be
appreciated. Here is the code:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/JDzezxVe
CSS:  http://pastebin.com/9vJvk0Sw

```css
*{margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;}
 
body{
    background:#CCC;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 900px;
}
 
.mainHeader{
        padding: 0;
        background:#666;
        height:36px;
        width:100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: -70px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #767373;
}
 
.mainHeader nav ul li{
        display:inline-block;
        list-style:none;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px -30px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top:  -128px;
    left: 10px;
}
 
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    font-family: 'Eras ITC';
}
 
.mainHeader nav ul li a:hover{
        background: #f18529;
}
 
.mainHeader nav ul .active {
        background: #f18529;
}
 
.mainInfo{
    background:white;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: -70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #727272 ;
}
 
.mainInfo .miInfo p{
    font-family: Arial;
    padding:  10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
 
.mainHeader .logoArea p{
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
   
}
 
.mainHeader .logoArea img{
    position: relative;
    top: -130px;
    left: 230px;
   
}
 
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    body{
    width: 100%;
}
   
    .mainHeader{
            padding: 0;
            background:#666;
            height:70px;
            width:80%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        left: -70px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
 
    .mainHeader nav ul li{
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        word-break: break-all;
 
}
 
 .mainHeader nav ul li a{
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        padding:  10px 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
       
}
 .mainInfo{
    background:white;
    height: 300px;
    width:80%;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: -70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #727272;
 
   
}
 
.mainInfo .miInfo{
 
}
 
 
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Website</title>
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <header class="mainHeader">
           <div class="logoArea">
                <img alt="logo" src="logo.jpg" width="250px" height="120px">
            </div>
            <nav><ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">Home<br/></a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About<br/></a></li>
                <li><a href="Random.html">Random</a></li>
            </ul></nav>
        </header>
 
        <div class="mainInfo">
            <div class="miInfo">
                <p>This is where you can put some side information about your site! The user will most likely
                see this part second! This is where you can put some side information about your site! The user will most likely
                see this part second! This is where you can put some side information about your site! The user will most likely
                see this part second! This is where you can put some side information about your site! The user will most likely
                see this part second! This is where you can put some side information about your site! The user will most likely
                see this part second! </p>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please copy that code into a Stack Overflow snippet so we can see how this works together.

Comment: Change the subject of this question to something actually descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to wrap around `.mainHeader nav ul`. Take `float:left;` off of `.mainHeader nav ul li` and you should be all set.